# Insert pages in the middle of a FragmentPageAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-adapter, viewpagerindicator

I'm using a ViewPager from [ViewPageIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) and I need to be able to **dynamically** insert one fragment in the **middle** of others.

I've tried to manage the model with *FragmentPagerAdapter* and *FragmentStatePagerAdapter* (both from v4 support code) and the first seems to don't manage in any way insertion of pages in the middle.
And the second only works if I make a naive implementation of **getItemPosition** returning always POSITION_NONE but this cause completly recreation of pages every time I swipe.

The problem I've observed with FragmentStatePagerAdapter  (FSP) is this:

- I start with two pages [A][B]
- Then I insert [C] in the middle [A][C][B]. After the insert I call **notifyDataSetchange()**
- Then FSP calls getItemPosition for [A] and gets 0
- Then FSP calls geTItemPosition for [B] and gets 2. And it says... Ohhh I've to destroy [B] and makes mFragments.set(2, null) and then as it only have two elements in mFragments array it throws an IndexOutOfBoundsException

After looking a little in the code it seems that provided fragmentStatePagerAdapter doesn't support insertion in the middle. Is that correct or I missing something?

**Update:**
The insert in the adapter is made in a logical way, when a certain codition is true the pages are incremented by one. The fragment creation is done using constructor in getItem() in that way:

```
void setCondition(boolean condition) {
   this.condition=condition;
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
public int getCount(){
    return condition?3:2;
}
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if(position==0) 
        return new A();
    else if(position==1)
        return condition?new C():new B();
    else if(position==2 && condition)
        return new B();
    else throw new RuntimeException("Not expected");
}
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    if(object instanceof A) return 0;
    else if(object instanceof B) return condition?2:1;
    else if(object instanceof C) return 1;
}
```

**Solution:**

As said in accepted answer the key is to implement `getItemId()`.

Make sure you use at least the [R9(June 2012) version of android-support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html). Because this method was added in it. Previous to this version that method doesn't exist and adapter doesn't manage correctly insertions.
Also make sure you use *FragmentPageAdapter* because FragmentStatePagerAdapter still doesn't works because it doesn't use ids.

Comment: What do you mean by "inserting"? How do you instantiate your Fragments in your PagerAdapter? Like this: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/using-newinstance-to-instantiate.html ? Or maybe just post the code of your Adapter and the way you insert it.

Comment: I create them using constructor. I've updated the question with more info.

Comment: Did you check if the ViewPager has three items if the `condition` is true on the creation of the Adapter (Activity)? If it does, than it's probably some problem with notifying. Interesting question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot about one method.
Override [getItemId(int position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html#getItemId%28int%29) from `FragmentPagerAdapter` which simply returns position to return something what will identify fragment instance.

```
public long getItemId(int position) {
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        return 0xA;
    case 1:
        return condition ? 0xC : 0xB;
    case 2:
        if (condition) {
            return 0xB;
        }
    default:
        throw new IllegalStateException("Position out of bounds");
    }
}
```

Comment: I had some confusion on that. I was working with revision 8 of support library. And the method you mention has appeared in R9 (June 2012) http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html.
In new revision FragmentPagerAdapter makes use of it and it works correctly. FragmentStatePagerAdapter doesn't seems to use it and still doesn't work correctly.